# Angular - ngClass already present before button click

Tags: angular, dom-events, angular-directive

The problem occurring now, correct class is already present when I load the page because of the condition I've put in, It finds **selectAnswer = false** and puts correct class in parent. Is there any way to tackle that?

**HTML**

```
<div class="question-options" *ngFor="let item of search.options;let j = index">
        <div class="statement-row" [ngClass]="(selectAnswer =='true')?'wrong':'correct'">
          <div class="statement-question">
            <div class="qitem-text">
              <div class="qitem-textbox">
                <p>{{item.statement}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ccq">
              <div class="qitem qclose" (click)="selectAnswer = 'true'">
                <i class="qitembox qclose-icon"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="qitem qtick" (click)="selectAnswer = 'false'">
                <i class="qitembox qtick-icon"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**TS**

```
  public selectAnswer = {};
```

I don't know how to manage the states in this case. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using for all different search options generated by that ngFor the same component proeprty, "selectAnswer" which can only hold one boolean value, making all other options change. Instead, to get your code working, try declaring in your component

```
public selectAnswer = {};
```

And

```
<div class="question-options" *ngFor="let item of search.options;let j = index">
    <div class="statement-row" [ngClass]="(selectAnswer[j] =='true')?'wrong':'correct'">
      <div class="statement-question">
        <div class="qitem-text">
          <div class="qitem-textbox">
            <p>{{item.statement}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ccq">
          <div class="qitem qclose" (click)="selectAnswer[j] = 'true'">
            <i class="qitembox qclose-icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="qitem qtick" (click)="selectAnswer[j] 'false'">
            <i class="qitembox qtick-icon"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

That should behave the way you wanted! There are other solutions but you can now take it from here, it can be improved depending on your needs.

**EDIT:** 
To get your classes not to get applied to your container until a first change has been made, you can add a new key to our selectAnswer object:

```
<div class="question-options" *ngFor="let item of search.options;let j = index">
<div class="statement-row" [ngClass]="{'correct': selectAnswer[j]?.dirty && (answer[j].select == 'true'), 'wrong': selectAnswer[j]?.dirty && (answer[j].select == 'false')}">
  <div class="statement-question">
    <div class="qitem-text">
      <div class="qitem-textbox">
        <p>{{item.statement}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ccq">
      <div class="qitem qclose" (click)="selectAnswer[j] = {select: 'true', dirty: 'true'};">
        <i class="qitembox qclose-icon"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="qitem qtick" (click)="selectAnswer[j] = {select: 'false', dirty: true};">
        <i class="qitembox qtick-icon"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. There's another issue, I've by-default correct class  due to the condition I've put. How to tackle that?

Comment: Make an edit section and update your question, i'll edit my answer

Comment: Edit section? Like stack blitz? Sorry, I'm a newbie

Comment: Update your stackoverflow question above and write a description of the new behaviour that you wish to find a solution to

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your model structure, but in item in your `*ngFor`

```
*ngFor="let item of search.options
```

the item should have property `selectAnswer`, for example

```
item.selectAnswer
```

then you code look like as follows

```html
<div class="question-options" *ngFor="let item of search.options;let j = index">
  <div class="statement-row" [ngClass]="(item.selectAnswer =='true')?'wrong':'correct'">
    <div class="statement-question">
      <div class="qitem-text">
        <div class="qitem-textbox">
          <p>{{item.statement}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ccq">
        <div class="qitem qclose" (click)="item.selectAnswer = 'true'">
          <i class="qitembox qclose-icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="qitem qtick" (click)="item.selectAnswer = 'false'">
          <i class="qitembox qtick-icon"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm just trying to toggle wrong or right class on div "statement-row", by clicking cross and tick respectively. Rest of my code is working

Comment: If I am not wrong you are telling that if you click on cross icon, The 'wrong' class is applied on  all the item in *ngFor  vice versa.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Well, that is solved Alejandro's answer did the job but there's another issue that I've mentioned under his answer

Comment: [ngClass]="{'correct': selectAnswer[j]== 'true', 'wrong': selectAnswer[j] == 'false')}